# Intellij IDEA: No beans of 'JdbcTemplate' type found

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Intellij IDEA 15.0.3 says that JdbcTemplate bean doesn't exist.

[image: idea error]

This is a Spring Boot project, so the all needed beans should be craeted inside of boot. It works fine and I can interact with my database but IDEA marks it like an error.
How can I fix it up?

> spring-boot-starter-jdbc is in pom.xml; Facets contain Spring; Project
>   Module has all needed dependencies; Spring boot version is 1.3.1

Comment: Is you Spring facet configured to include your `@SpringBootAplication` and/or other context you're using?

Comment: Yes it is. My Spring facet includes class which has annotation  @SpringBootAplication

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem. My project works but only intellij shows this error. Smells like some bug.

Comment: Sometimes IntelliJ does not correctly associate configuration files with your classes correctly.  This seems to be the case, since your application runs just fine.  You can disable this error notification by right-clicking on the `jdbcTemplate` field and choosing to ignore the autowiring inspection for the field or class.

Comment: @woemler Yes thats true, but how to actually fix this?

Answer (score 6):

After Intellij IDEA 2016.1.2, click Help->Edit Custom Properties, add new line with `idea.spring.boot.filter.autoconfig=false` and restart IDE, then the problem can be fixed.
You can check details in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139669

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Project structure -> Facets. Be sure to have Spring Boot facet for the given module and that all configuration classes are added to `Spring Appliction Context` group.