# Could not autowire. No beans of 'JdbcTemplate' type found

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I try to use JdbcTemplate on a local springboot project, but I have an error when I try to use it. The attribute jdbctemplate is underlined in red in the constructor with the error message:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'JdbcTemplate' type found

I don't have stacktrace, just the underlined word.

This is my repository class:

```
package projet.thesquad.repository;

    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import projet.thesquad.domain.Member;
    
    @Repository
    public class MemberRepository {
    
        private final String ADD_MEMBER_REQUEST = "INSERT INTO TheSquad.Member (fistname, lastname, job) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    
        private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
        public MemberRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }
    
        public int addMember(Member member) {
            return jdbcTemplate.update(ADD_MEMBER_REQUEST, member.getFirstname(), member.getLastname(), member.getJob());
        }
    }
```

This is my build.Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.21'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.21'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Comment: Are you using Intellij IDEA ?

Comment: You force spring to have a `JdbcTemplate` available during instantiation of `MemberRepository` as you are not providing an empty constructor. So you should also create a `@Bean` of type `JdbcTemplate` somewhere in your code. Or you provide the `DataSource` to your repository, then you can create the template like `this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);`

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad yes I use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij IDEA: No beans of 'JdbcTemplate' type found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522308/intellij-idea-no-beans-of-jdbctemplate-type-found)

Comment: use ```@Autowired``` before your constructor declaration

Comment: I try to use @Autowired but it's the same result.  I have to create a new class DataSource ?